Mixamo (using Blender V 3.6) Control Rig - Tweaking Question re Keyframes
I'd like to give a real world example to describe the problem I face.
I have successfully created an action strip in the NLA, and have applied an animation, in this example, a man sitting at a desk writing. I would now like the man to look up instead of down. I enter tweak mode and am able to manipulate the character to lean back and look up.
I go to the next keyframe, he is looking down! I see some fiddly ways to correct this keyframe by keyframe (and element by element eg - spine/neck/head) - but surely there is a way to auto copy all subsequent keyframes - and on all elements - as I amend each subsequent keyframe. I have been able to go through each 'element' and change or copy/paste the correct dimensions - I can't see how I can do this with an e.g. global keyframe... can't find solution on search engines as hard to include the fact I would like to use the control rig from Mixamo.... Hope you can help.

There are many ways for dealing with this situation, some of them:

Use graph editor to manipulate an entire channel curve instead of a single keyframe. You can also use proportional editing in graph editor, to modify a "zone" of influence of the new editing.

Add a new bone, acting as parent of the old one, which can be use to add animation data "on top" of the existing animation.

Use "Layered animation": when a strip is acting on NLA, you can add a new action in the action editor, click on the orangy name of the new action in the NLA, and set its influence blending mode (generally Combine or Replace), and its behaviour when the strip finishes (Hold, Hold forward or Nothing). Be sure to have a complete comprehension of theese two important parameters before animating, because they can be misleading and confusing.


Now you can add some keyframes "on top" of existing animation data, push down the new action when finished, then add as many animation layers as you want.
As example, in the situation you describe for the head, I would add a new action, set it to "Combine" and "Hold", and add a single keyframe to reorient the head for the entire animation.

